# How to disable (i dont want it to be shown) a transformation but take its value in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql, rate

I'm using Grafana to create a panel which shows some basic values.

I have here "success rate", which is calculated as "success jobs" / "total jobs". Using "success rate" I create "success %".
I want only "success %" to be in the panel.

[image: grafana panel image]

Comment: @Brad, please avoid using code syntax for something other than code. For outlining terms or important information you can use _cursive_, __bold__ or simple quotes depending on situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Organise fields](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#organize-fields) transformation to hide fields.
[image: Organize fields transformation]

---

Additionally, you could remove your transformation which calculates the percentage. Instead, you can set the [unit](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-standard-options/#unit) via panel options and Grafana will automatically render it as a percentage.

[image: Panel Unit]